# MongoDB Query with group by

Tags: sql, mongodb, group-by

I would like to run a query in mongodb that looks like the following (in SQL). The output should be stored into a cursor.

```
SELECT ipv4 src, SUM(flags) 
FROM table 
WHERE starttime > 1262300400 AND endtime < y AND port dst = 22 
GROUP BY ipv4, src
```

I read http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/

and tried

```
myCursor = db.mycol.find(  [  
  {$group:{ _id: "$src",total:{$sum:"$flags"}}},
  {$match:{$and:[{"dst":22},
          {$and:[{"starttime":{$gt:1262300400}},{"endtime":{$lt:1264978800}}]}]}  
  }  ]);
```

but it failed.

BTW: Can I search between two unix-timestamps by just checking the range between those? In the example above I tried to search for a time between `1262300400` and `1264978800`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `aggregate` method instead of `find` to do this and you don't need to use all those `$and` operators in the `$match` as the fields are naturally ANDed.  And put the `$match` operation first so that you're not `$group`ing on more docs than you need to.

```js
db.mycol.aggregate([
    {$match:{"dst":22, "starttime":{$gt:1262300400}, "endtime":{$lt:1264978800}}},
    {$group:{ _id:"$src", total:{$sum:"$flags"}}}
]);
```

Comment: Hi, Now I'm getting the error "TypeError: db.mycol.aggregate is not a function myjavascript.js:182" (line 182: the query)

Comment: @Tyzak `aggregate` requires MongoDB v2.2 and the latest drivers.  Sounds like you might be out of date.